Help with Order Total Formula Using ISPICKVAL for two separate fields
I'm attempting a formula that allows the user to change the Tax Rate on an order by overriding the standard tax rate (Tax_Rate__c) and multiply by the new tax rate (New_Tax_Rate__c) if the user selects the picklist value of YES in a field (Override_Tax_Rate__c).  But I want to add this to the current formula below (this formula allows the user to make the order tax exempt which I need to keep as part of it still).
Here is the CURRENT formula that I'd like to add to (need to keep this formula too):
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "No"), 
    Order_Subtotal__c * Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c,
    Order_Subtotal__c
)

This is what I've tried:
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "No"),
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Override_Tax_Rate__c), "Yes"),
        Order_Subtotal__c * Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c,
        Order_Subtotal__c,
        Order_Subtotal__c * New_Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c,
        Order_Subtotal__c
)


Have you tried to modify your existing formula at all? Even if it doesn't work, showing us your attempt will help people give you more targeted advice. Also, if you need to bone up on formulas a bit, then the formulas and validations module on trailhead would be a good place to start.

as a hint to get you going in the right direction, you can use an IF() inside of another IF(). E.g. IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 6, IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 3, 'First Quarter', 'Second Quarter'), 'Third or Fourth Quarter'). Also, breaking things up onto additional lines makes it a lot easier to see what's going on. I can't do that here in the comments, but that's what I did for your existing formula. Newlines and indentation.

You weren't too far off.
Each IF() takes only and exactly 3 parameters, IF(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)
The first condition is ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "No"), when that's true, you want to use Tax_Rate__c
If Tax_Exempt__c is not "No", then you want to test for if it's "Yes" (and use the other tax rate)
So you're looking at
IF(
    /* condition */
    ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "No"),
    /* here, we know the condition is true. This is the "then" part */
    Order_Subtotal__c * Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c,
    /* here, we know the condition is false. This is the "else" part */
    /* time to do the second check */
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "Yes"),
        Order_Subtotal__c * New_Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c,
        Order_Subtotal__c
    )
)

The inner IF() has 3 parameters
and the third parameter for the outer IF() is the entirety of the inner IF()
There is still room for improvement though. Instead of saying Order_Subtotal__c * Tax_Rate__c + Order_Subtotal__c, you can add 1 to the tax rate to achieve the same thing. Using parenthesis so that PEMDAS doesn't screw us over...
Order_Subtotal__c * (1 + Tax_Rate__c) (or New_Tax_Rate__c, as appropriate)
There's still more improvement that can be done.
The CASE() function can work directly on picklists, and using that will make the formula "flatter" (i.e. less indentation required)
/* CASE() takes a string, a picklist, etc... as its first parameter */
/* followed by target value - result pairs */
/* finally ending with a default result to use if none of the pairs are matched */
CASE( 
    Tax_Exempt__c,
    "No", Order_Subtotal__c * (1 + Tax_Rate__c),
    "Yes", Order_Subtotal__c * (1 + New_Tax_Rate__c),
    Order_Subtotal__c
)

There's still one more level of simplification that we can do here.
Since Order_Subtotal__c appears in each of the result values for the CASE(), we can factor that out just like in algebra.
/* The final form */
/* We're always using the subtotal, we just need to figure out what */
/*   to multiply it by */
Order_Subtotal__c *
CASE( 
    Tax_Exempt__c,
    "No", (1 + Tax_Rate__c),
    "Yes", (1 + New_Tax_Rate__c),
    1
)
/* We could also factor out the '1', but at that point we're starting to harm */
/*   readability */
/* The main reasons to refine the formula this far is to: */
/* 1: reduce the amount of typing (the more we type, the more chances there */
/*      are to make a mistake) */
/* 2: make it easier for people to read and understand (and modify) */

To help demonstrate the "make it easier to modify" part, here's what the refined formula would look like for your original formula
Order_Subtotal__c *
CASE( 
    Tax_Exempt__c,
    "No", (1 + Tax_Rate__c),
    1
)

The modification in this case being that we just added another target value - result pair
+edit: ok, I misread the question a bit.
Since "tax exempt" and "override tax rate" are separate fields, we can't really use CASE() here. At least, not in a way that makes things easy to read.
So we end up with
/* Although we can't use CASE() here */
/*   we can still use the other optimizations like pulling */
/*   Order_Subtotal__c out of the IF()s */
Order_Subtotal__c * 
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "No"),
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Override_Tax_Rate__c, "Yes"),
        1 + New_Tax_Rate__c,
        1 + Tax_Rate__c
    ),
    1
)

Though now that I think about it a little more, it's probably safer to assume that tax always applies unless Tax_Exempt__c is "Yes".
Not much of a change, but if Tax_Exempt__c happens to be null/blank/empty, then you probably want tax to be applied.
/* Although we can't use CASE() here */
/*   we can still use the other optimizations like pulling */
/*   Order_Subtotal__c out of the IF()s */
Order_Subtotal__c * 
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Tax_Exempt__c, "Yes"),
    /* Just swapping the "then" and "else" parts so that the formula */
    /*   still does what you want it to */
    1,
    IF(
        /* This IF() is already structured appropriately */
        /* No changes required */
        ISPICKVAL(Override_Tax_Rate__c, "Yes"),
        1 + New_Tax_Rate__c,
        1 + Tax_Rate__c
    )
)

